# Jhipster Microservice and Hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, hystrix

I have created a Microservice with JHipster and I want to add hystrix, but I have a problem.

I had `@EnableHystrix` on my `ServiceApp.java`, and `@HystrixCommand` on method `@RequestMapping`.

But when I want to access on `http://localhost:8081/hystrix.stream` (it's the good port), I get this page:

> Your request cannot be processed

I do not know from where it comes, security problem, but I can't solve it successfully.

Thanks for your help. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Jhipster sets by default the actuator property management.context-path to /management

So your hystrix stream should be available at http://localhost:8081/management/hystrix.stream

Comment: I have the same problem with  http://localhost:8081/management/hystrix.stream , i have also add this line in MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration : .antMatchers("/management/**").permitAll()